# How to make two columns layout HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm creating online shop.
I want to create two column layout.
On the left side will be the tab gallery. On the right side i want to display the options for purchase like size,quantity,color,button for buy and etc. 
I'm using bootstrap.
I want to doing something like this: 
[online shop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiGsx.png)
This is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KYeWPj): `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KYeWPj`

I have this code:

```js
/*google analytics js */
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  font-family: 'helvetive neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.thumbnails {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-left: -2%;
}

.thumbnails li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.thumbnails li:hover .item-hugger {
  background: white;
}

.thumbnails li:hover .item-hugger .title {
  color: #000;
}

.thumbnails input[name="select"] {
  display: none;
}

.thumbnails .item-hugger {
  position: relative;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.thumbnails label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbnails .title {
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
}

.thumbnails .thumb-image {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.thumbnails .content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.thumbnails .content .title {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #555;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #fe7701;
  padding: 50px 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.thumbnails input[name="select"]:checked+.item-hugger {
  height: 180px;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}

.thumbnails input[name="select"]:checked~.content {
  opacity: 1;
}

.white-box {
  background: white;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"  integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<!--   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Item</title>
  
    </head>-->

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 style="margin-top:40px; text-align:center">Item</h1>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="select" id="image1">
        <div class="item-hugger">
          <div class="title">Image 1</div>
          <img class="thumb-image" src="https://unsplash.it/289/165?image=882" />
          <label for="image1"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="item-wrapper"> <img src="https://unsplash.it/1024/612?image=882" />
            <div class="title">Image 1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="is-active">
        <input type="radio" name="select" id="image2" checked>
        <div class="item-hugger">
          <div class="title">Image 2</div>
          <img class="thumb-image" src="https://unsplash.it/289/165?image=782" />
          <label for="image2"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="item-wrapper">
          <img src="https://unsplash.it/1024/612?image=782" />
            <div class="title">Image 2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="select" id="image3">
        <div class="item-hugger">
          <div class="title">Image 3</div>
          <img class="thumb-image" src="https://unsplash.it/289/165?image=682" />
          <label for="image3"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="item-wrapper"> 
            <img src="https://unsplash.it/1024/612?image=682" />
            <div class="title">Image 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="select" id="image4">
        <div class="item-hugger">
          <div class="title">Image 4</div>
          <img class="thumb-image" src="https://unsplash.it/289/165?image=582" />
          <label for="image4"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="item-wrapper"> 
          <img src="https://unsplash.it/1024/612?image=582" />
            <div class="title">Image 4</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="white-box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would politely suggest you go away and carry out a course to learn how to code. There are many courses available and I suggest using something like [Treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/) . Your code as you have currently is a long way away from best practise. Good luck.

Comment: Please restructure your code into a code snippet and remove all code that is not relevant to your question (analytics, jquery, meta, ...).

Comment: I agree with @Martin. I would recommend [freecodecamp.org](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/). It's completely free. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A really easy way of doing this would be to use a table. It doesn't require any CSS, just a simple table that doesn't have a visible border.

The way you do this is putting a `<tr>` tag around the content you want to align by each other and a `<table>` tag surrounding the `<tr>` tags. It should look like this:
`<table><tr>YOUR ELEMENTS</tr></table>`.

Now, take each of your elements that you'd like to be aligned side-by-side and put them in their own `<td>` tags. This is what it should look like now:

```
<td>Left</td>
<td>Center</td>
<td>Right</td>
</tr></table>
```

This should fix your problem. If you, for whatever reason, see borders around your elements you can to `<table style="border: none;">` instead of just saying `<table>`. Hope this helped!